# Windows Phone App (Windows 8.1) does not show detailed information about my phone

Tags: sync, gdr-3

I have the [Windows Phone App (the Metro one for Windows 8.1)](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-CA/app/windows-phone/0e0fbaf6-fd99-4046-b494-9ce469ae3009) installed, but when I plug in my phone (unlocked HTC 8x running GDR3) all it shows is the phone's name, phone number, and battery life. I can't see the storage usage, pictures, or music as the Metro app's store page promises. I'm thinking that this may be because the Metro app was never updated for GDR3. Does anyone else have this problem?

EDIT: Since updating to Windows Phone 8.1 this is no longer a problem.

Comment: If it's any use, it works for me. Windows 8.1 on the PC, GDR3 on the phone (Ascend W1, developer unlocked). In the Windows Phone App, I've got automatic import turned off. And check your permissions.

Comment: Just tested a Lumia 820 (GDR3) and a Lumia 720 (GDR2) and it works. If the phone has no pictures or music, they won't show in the app. Does your phone and its contents show in Windows Explorer?

Comment: @NeilTurner I can see the phone and access its contents through Windows Explorer

Comment: Other than re-installing the Windows Phone app, I'm not too sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use other ways to manage your data on you Phone.

1. Via the Windows Phone Desktop App.
   You can download it here:
   http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop
2. Via Windows Media Player (Only music)
3. Via explorer (Go to 'This PC', your Windows Phone shows up there)